# flutter_svg not loading some svg files

Tags: flutter

I am unable to open certain svg files with [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package

example of file is [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-UD3FCDQNBmqFFcecyubirAdcEqcuXdg/view?usp=sharing)

I wanted to make sure there is nothing I am missing before I may be open an issue

I am getting no error back just an empty  space

the code for loading the image

```
SvgPicture.asset(
      "assets/svg/agaseke_logo.svg",
       color: Color(0xFF0bd50b),
      height: 45,
      width: 25,
    ),
```

Comment: Are you having an error? If so please post the stack trace. Add some code you have used to display the image and if you dont get an error, send a screen shot of where the image should have been. Try using the place holder property to see if there is a problem with the library or with the image provided

Comment: edited the question, I am getting no error back just an empty space @SiddharthAgrawal

Comment: If you look at the flutter_svg documentation they state that they don't support CSS, which your file relies on for the colour of at least some the shapes. First try removing that and putting the fill on each of the items directly. If that doesn't help, next I'd try stripping out most of the paths, checking whether that worked, then re-adding them a few at time to ensure it still worked (you could create multiple files and switch between them to avoid rebuilds for now). If you can pinpoint which path is having issues you're much more likely to get help from the creators.